# Does media queries work for all smart phones

Tags: mobile, css, media-queries

I am trying to develop a mobile application, which should run on all smartphones, tablets and some feature phones. I have used CSS3 media queries before and tested in Android and iOS, where it works like a charm. But what about Nokia and Bada OS, does this work ?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/ releated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take a look at the indispensable [Mobile compatibility chart](http://quirksmode.org/mobile/) from Peter-Paul Koch. Media Queries are pretty well supported, as long as the browser is Opera, Firefox or uses the Webkit engine (virtually all modern mobile browsers do). You might have some trouble getting it to work on older Blackberries and Windows Mobile 7 and lower though.

Comment: IE9 Mobile on Windows Phone 7.5 also supports Media Queries quite well: http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/22/targeting-mobile-optimized-css-at-windows-phone-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks, changed my answer to include that.